# Finding the Kth Largest element in a Python List using recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Given an input list that contains some random unsorted numbers, I am trying to write a program that outputs the kth largest distinct element in that list. For example:

```
Input: 
el = [10,10, 20,30,40, 40]
k = 2
Output: 30 #Since 30 is the second largest distinct element in the list
```

The following function, takes as input a list, the pivot Index and k and populates list *"lesser"* with all elements lesser than the pivot and populates another list *"greater"* with all elements greater than the pivot.

Now, looking at the length of the two list, I can determine if the kth largest element is in the lesser list or the greater list. Now I recursively call the same function. However, my program's output is wrong for certain values of k.

```
def kthLargest(el, pivotIndex, k):
    pivot = el[pivotIndex]
    lesser = [] #List to store all elements lesser than pivot
    greater = [] #Lsit to store all elements greater than pivot
    equals = [] #List to store all elements equal to pivot

    for x in el:
        if x > pivot:
            greater.append(x)
        elif x < pivot:
            lesser.append(x)
        else:
            equals.append(x)
    g = len(greater) #Length of greater list
    l = len(lesser) 

    if(g == k - 1): #If greater list has k-1 elements, that makes the pivot kth largest element
        return pivot
    elif(g < k):
        return kthLargest(lesser, l - 1, k) #If greater list is smaller than k, kth largest element is in lesser list
    else:
        return kthLargest(greater,  g - 1, k) #Else kth largest element is in greater list
```

Comment: I assume this is a homework question? For an effective solution, there's `numpy.partition`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an easy way to do this problem using recursion.  I'm just not sure why you need the pivot in the problem description... For example:

```
def find_kth(k, arr):
    if k == 1:
        return max(arr)
    m = max(arr)
    new_arr = list(filter(lambda a: a != m, arr))
    return(find_kth(k-1, new_arr))
```

Comment: This looks inefficient and will exceed the recursion limit for large values of k.

Comment: I was aiming for simplicity over efficiency for this problem.  Furthermore, OP _asks_ for recursion, which will of course overflow for large values of `k`, so not sure what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you want to use recursion? To find the kth largest element of a list you have to look through the entire list, so the problem is essentially O(n) complexity anyway.

You could do this without recursion like this:

```
el = [10, 10, 53, 20, 30, 40, 59, 40]
k = 2

def kth_largest(input_list, k):
    # initialize the top_k list to first k elements and sort descending
    top_k = input_list[0:k]
    top_k.sort(reverse = True)

    for i in input_list[k:]:
        if i > top_k[-1]:
            top_k.pop() # remove the lowest of the top k elements
            top_k.append(i) # add the new element
            top_k.sort(reverse = True) # re-sort the list

    return top_k[-1] # return the kth largest


kth_largest(el, k)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
def kthmax(k, list):
    if (k == 1):
        return max(list)
    else:
        m = max(list)
        return(kthmax(k-1, [x for x in list if x != m]))

kthmax(3,[4, 6, 2, 7, 3, 2, 6, 6])
```

Output: 4

Answer (score 0):

If we can pass in a list or series that is already sorted in descending 
order, e.g

```
el.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace = True)
```

then you can easily find the kth largest (index,value) tuple
using just simple slicing of sorted dataframe column and/or list

```
def kth_largest(input_series, k):
    new_series = input_series[k-1:len(input_series)]
    return (np.argmax(new_series) , np.max(new_series))

el = pd.Series([10, 10, 53, 20, 30, 40, 59, 40])
print el
k = 2

el.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)

print kth_largest(el, 2)

Output: 30
0    10
1    10
2    53
3    20
4    30
5    40
6    59
7    40
dtype: int64
(2, 53)
```

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm: Take the index of max value and convert to zero.

```
def high(arr,n):
    for i in range(n+ 1 ):
        arr[arr.index(max(arr))] = 0
        return max(arr)
high([1,2,3,4,5], 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

My way of finding the Kth largest element is...

```
lst=[6,2,3,4,1,5]
print(sorted(lst,reverse=True)[k-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of S Rohith Kumar's answer, If the input has duplicate values, then the answer can be :

```
print(sorted(set(lst),reverse=True)[k-1])
```