# Finding third largest element in the list without using len() and sort()

Tags: python, list

Here is the code which I used to find the third largest element in the list without using any built in functions like max,sort,len.

```
list = [12, 45, 2, 41, 31, 10, 8, 6, 4]
#list = [35,10,45,9,8,5]
largest_1 = list[0]
largest_2 = list[0]
largest_3 = list[0]
print (largest_1)
print (largest_2)
print (largest_3)
for each in list:
    print ('Each element Before if Loop --->',each)
    if each > largest_1:
        print ('Each element inside if loop --->',each)
        largest_1 = each
        print('largest_1 element---->',largest_1)
    elif largest_2 != largest_1 and largest_2 < each:
        print ('Each element inside if loop --->',each)
        largest_2 = each 
        print ('Largest_1 element is ---->',largest_1)
        print ('Largest_2 element is ---->',largest_2)
    elif largest_3 != largest_2  and largest_3 < each:
        print ('Each element inside if loop --->',each)
        largest_3 = each
        print ('Largest_2 element is ---->',largest_2)
        print ('Largest_3 element is ---->',largest_3)

print (largest_1)
print (largest_2)
print (largest_3)
```

The same code is not working for the

```
list = [35,10,45,9,8,5]
```

I am not getting what mistake I have done. How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the Kth Largest element in a Python List using recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089413/finding-the-kth-largest-element-in-a-python-list-using-recursion)

Comment: @GaneshK, Hey buddy i dont want to use any max in my code. Its not a duplicate

Comment: Your question does not state that anywhere.

Comment: @venkat You can't use any libraries?

Comment: @RoadRunner, yes

Comment: @venkat put your `largest_2 and largest_3` equal to `0` and you're done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you wouldn't want to use `len()`, or `max()` - they're literally built-in functions, not part of any library, and there's no practical reason not to use them. That said, if you really want to do it otherwise, here's another approach:

Take three variables, assign them `largest`, `second_largest`, and `third_largest`, and walk through the list.

```
largest = 0
second_largest = 0
third_largest = 0

for each in list:
    if each >= largest:
        # assign the new largest, and push the rest of them back down the chain
        # we use >= instead of > to ensure that duplicate maximums still work.
        #   
        largest, second_largest, third_largest = each, largest, second_largest
    elif each >= second_largest:
        second_largest, third_largest = each, second_largest
    elif each > third_largest:
        third_largest = each
print(third_largest)
```

Answer (score 3):

@venkat: Here another proposal to get the third largest number out of your list without using `len()` and `sort()`.

```
def find_largest(alist):
    """
    Find the largest number in a list.

    Return the largest number found and it index
    """
    largest = alist[0]
    for item in alist[1:]:
        if item > largest:
            largest = item

    idx =  alist.index(largest)
    return (idx, largest)

#--
def get_third_largest(alist):
    """
    Return the third largest number in a list.
    """
    # Let make a copy of the input list so that any change to it may not affect the
    # original data.
    thisList = alist.copy()

    index, largest = 0, 0
    for item in range(3):
        index, largest = find_largest(thisList)
        if item != 2:
            # delete the first two largest from the List
            del thisList[index]
    return largest

# Test of the algorithm
if __name__ == "__main__":
    List = [12, 45, 2, 41, 31, 10, 8, 6, 4]
    third = get_third_largest(List)
    # print("Initial list: ", List)
    # print("The third largest item in the list:")
    print("\tExpected: 31")
    print("\tResult:   %d" % third);

# --- Output---
# Expected: 31
# Result:   31
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also store your top 3 max numbers in a dictionary, then print out the third largest one:

```
largest = {"first": 0, "second": 0, "third": 0}

lst = [12, 45, 2, 41, 31, 10, 8, 6, 4]

for number in lst:
    if number > largest["first"]:
        largest["third"] = largest["second"]
        largest["second"] = largest["first"]
        largest["first"] = number
    elif number > largest["second"]:
        largest["third"] = largest["second"]
        largest["second"] = number
    elif number > largest["third"]:
        largest["third"] = number

print(largest)
# {'first': 45, 'second': 41, 'third': 31}

print(largest["third"])
# 31
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [12, 45, 2, 41, 31, 10, 8, 6, 4]
c = 0
for i in list:
  c+=1
  for j in range(c):
      for k in range(j):
          if list[j] > list[k]:
              list[j], list[k] = list[k],list[j]
          else:
              list[j],list[k] = list[j],list[k]
print(list[2]," is the third largest element")
```

Comment: An explanation of how and why your code works and addresses the question would be ideal.  Remember, you are leaving solutions not just for the original asker but for future users, so providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.