# Randomly sample from dataframe based on condition without losing data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sample

I've been doing this in VBA but would really appreciate advice on how to do it pythonically.
I've got an Excel sheet with 8000+ rows and >25 columns.  I need to mark certain rows as requiring close review by a human.  Basically, for each individual in the 'Name' column, we need to randomly flag 10% of that person's rows as needing review.  We *don't* want to lose/delete/suppress the other rows; they need to remain available--that's why I'm thinking `df.sample` wouldn't work.  In the actual data, there will  be 20-30 unique Names, each with 300-400 rows.

So far I've used pandas to read the data into a dataframe, done some stuff which isn't germane to this question, and written the dataframe back into an Excel file.  As part of this, I've also created a 'Random_No.' column in the dataframe, thinking this would be a useful step towards my goal (''based on how I was doing it in VBA)...maybe invoking something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089413/finding-the-kth-largest-element-in-a-python-list-using-recursion#57966240) for each Name.

There's probably a million ways to do this, and I've been fiddling with various approaches, but I'd really appreciate some advice on what you think the most efficient way would be.  I seem to be creating a lot of 'helper' dataframes and series and ArrayOfObjects...and in general making everything more complicated than it probably needs to be.  **Is there a *simple* way to do this within the dataframe** as opposed to making a newbie-Python mess?

Here's a simplified schema of the data; the 'Needs_review' represents the kind of column I'm trying to create--again, 10% for each Name. As always thanks for any advice/direction.

[image: ![simplified view of data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using side effect

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': [f"Name_{i}" for i in np.random.randint(0,10,10000)],
    'Col1': np.random.randn(10000)})

need_review = []
df.groupby(['Name']).agg(
    lambda x: need_review.extend(
        np.random.choice(
            x.index, int(0.1*len(x.index)), replace=False).tolist())).unstack()
df['Needs_Review'] = False
df.loc[need_review, 'Needs_Review'] = True

print (df.groupby(['Name', 'Needs_Review'])['Needs_Review'].count())
```

Output:

```
Name    Needs_Review
Name_0  False           871
        True             96
Name_1  False           925
        True            102
Name_2  False           895
        True             99
Name_3  False           890
        True             98
Name_4  False           842
        True             93
Name_5  False           932
        True            103
Name_6  False           911
        True            101
Name_7  False           932
        True            103
Name_8  False           909
        True            101
Name_9  False           898
        True             99
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks @mujjiga.  I just wonder if any other Python newbies might get a little confused between choice (as a list) and np.random.choice.

Comment: @PE agreed, changed to a better variable name.

Answer (score 0):

I’m answering my own question here but also appealing for any improvements. Also maybe this is of use to other Python newbies.

First, thanks again to @mujjiga, whose solution worked very well in the dataframe he generated, but I found when I used it on my own data I got very erratic results.  Which is a shame, because with my data it took between 2 and 3 seconds, which I didn’t think was too bad.  (Saying that, it took about that long in VBA.)

So I fiddled around and came up with a few things that work—but I’d appreciate any suggestions for improvement.

**First**, I tried to continue to do something with `apply(lambda`.  This got the job done, but it took a shocking 23 seconds:

```
percent = 10 #<-- CHANGE THIS AS NEEDED
def do_it(x):
        gk  = df[['Name','Random']].groupby('Name')
        tm = gk.get_group(x)
        lst = sorted(tm.Random)
        lim = lst[int(len(lst)*percent*0.01)]
        return lim   #here and below, 'lim' represents the number below which we select a row for randomisation
df['Needs_Review']=df.apply(lambda x: 'Randomised' if x['Random'] < do_it(x['Name']) else ' ',axis=1)
```

**Second approach**.  Basically this replicated with what I did in VBA:  loop through each of the ~25 names, and at each name loop through the 8000+ rows of data.  It got the job done too, and surprisingly (to me) came in a little faster, at 21 seconds:

```
nms = df.Name.unique()  #get unique Names
df['Needs_Review']= ' '    #this adds empty column
percent = 10 #<-- CHANGE THIS AS NEEDED
percent = 100/percent
for i in range(0,len(nms)):  #iterate through names
        tm = gk.get_group(nms[i])
        lst = sorted(tm.Random)
        lim = lst[int( len(lst)*percent*0.01)] 
        for index, row in df.iterrows(): #now iterate through data rows
            if nms[i]==row['Name']:  #check if row matches Name
                if row['Random'] < lim:
                    df.loc[index,'Needs_Review'] = 'Randomised'
```

**Third approach**.  But everything I read about Python says ‘*avoid for loops—vectorise!*’.  So I fiddled some more and came up with this, using `np.where`.  It works—in less than half a second!

```
nms = df.Name.unique()   #get unique Names
df['Needs_Review']= ''  #this adds empty column
percent = 10 #<-- CHANGE THIS AS NEEDED
for i in range(0,len(nms)):  #as you can see, I'm still iterating with a for-loop...
    tm  = df['Name']==nms[i]    
    tempy = df[tm] #this dataframe contains 1 Name at a time
    lim = sorted(tempy['Random'])[int(len(sorted(tempy['Random']))*percent*0.01)]
    #we want to flag any rows where Random =< lim

    
    fix = (df['Random']<=lim) & df['Name'].str.contains(nms[i]) #sets up a boolean condition
    keep = df['Needs_Review'] #this series represents the 'Needs_Review' column so far
    df['Needs_Review'] = np.where(fix, 'Randomised', keep) #replaces cells in 'Needs_Review' column if they meet the 'fix' boolean condition; otherwise existing values are re-inserted
```

Well, that’s pretty cool.  So why am I still pestering you all?  Because I’m still using a ‘for loop’, iterating through each of my ~25 names.  I’m sure there’s a way to get rid of that too.  The performance improvement will be marginal with this dataset, but the principle of the thing is nagging me.  **Any ideas how I could vectorise the Name loop too?**  Apologies form my clumsiness with terminology.